# Linux: Extract the first line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openwrt

I am working with OpenWrt and a *very* small amount of space.

Trying to extract the first line from a file. The line needs to go into a variable and be removed from the file. I can use `head` to put it into a variable but can't use `tail` because as far as I understand I would have to do `tail file > newFile` and I do not have room for that second file.

Does some one know if a better technic?

Comment: You're not going to be able to avoid reading and rewriting the entire file. Perhaps this can be done in-place, but most tools don't because a failure will cause a partial result. What file is this? Perhaps there is another solution that doesn't involve the actual removal of the line.

Comment: It's a raw text file in a specific format that I am getting from curl and pushing to hardware via Netcat

Comment: @Mikael The best way is to filter the file *before* writing it down to disk.

Comment: @jofel That's a great idea. How do I do that? When I put the Curl response into a variable it losses the "returns" so it's all on the first line.

Comment: @Mikael An easy option could be to download the file twice. First time, filter only the first line. Second time, skip it and save the rest.

Comment: @Mikael: I have update my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24285694/1182783) with another option with only one curl call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: you can't use my old answer (see below) with OpenWrt since OpenWrt doesn't ship with `ed`. What a shame. So here are two methods:

### The `vi` way

`vi` is a genuine editor too, so the following will work:

```
vi -c ':1d' -c ':wq' file > /dev/null
```

We open the file with `vi`, and use the commands `:1d` to delete the first line and `:wq` to save and quit, redirecting all output to `/dev/null`. Cool, clean, short and simple.

Oh, you will of course run:

```
firstline=$(head -n1 file)
```

before running this `vi` command to get the first line of the file into the variable `firstline`.

**Note.** On a system with very little memory, and when `file` is huge, this method fails.

### The `dd` way

`dd` is a cool tool for this. The `dd` methods given in other answers are really great, yet they rely on the `truncate` utility which does not ship with OpenWrt. Here's a workaround:

```
firstline=$(head -n1 file)
linelength=$(head -n1 file | wc -c)
newsize=$(( $(wc -c < file) - $linelength ))
dd if=file of=file bs=1 skip=$linelength conv=notrunc
dd if=/dev/null of=file bs=1 count=0 seek=$newsize
```

This will work even with huge files and very little memory! The last `dd` command plays the role of the `truncate` command given in the other answers.

---

Old answer was:

You can use `ed` for this:

```
firstline=$(printf '%s\n' 1p d wq | ed -s file.txt)
```

At each call, you'll get the first line of the file `file.txt` in the variable `firstline`, and this line is removed from the file.

Comment: This works perfectly on my Mac but not on the OpenWrt device. It's running ash.

Comment: One suggested change: `linelength=${#firstline}` instead of `linelength=$(head -n1 file | wc -c)` because the latter can add a space before the number and cause the `skip` to be without parameters.

Comment: @Mikael Do you have an example of a line where `wc -c` would add a space before the number? Now, there's a difference between `linelength=${#firstline}` and `linelength=$(head -n1 | wc -c)`: the former will not count the newline character, and the latter will (and you want it to be counted!). Also, it seems that `${#firstline}` will indeed count the number of bytes (what you want), but in some systems, `${#firstline}` would rather count the number of characters. These may differ—think of wide characters, e.g., `\xc3\xa9` which is the one character `é`, utf8-encoded on 2 bytes.

Comment: @Mikael: I'd really like to see a line where `wc -c` leaves a leading whitespace. Now, if this really happens, you'd better use: `linelength=$(head -n1 file | wc -c)` as prescribed, followed by a removal of the possible leading whitespace with `linelength=$((linelength))`.

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion and it works. For the sake of posterity this is the output:
`++ head -n1 file`
`+ firstline=3048`
`++ head -n1 file`
`++ wc -c`
`+ linelength='       5'`
`+ linelength=5`

Comment: @Mikael interesting... which version of OpenWrt and BusyBox do you have? (this doesn't happen with OpenWrt 12.09 with BusyBox v1.19.4`).

Comment: This is happening on my mac. I tested that it was working I the router but now I am fine tuning the code on the mac. In fact it seems wc always give me leading space?

Comment: @Mikael maybe it adds leading whitespaces on mac, I have no idea. GNU `wc` doesn't, and BusyBox's `wc` doesn't either (it seems). Anyways, you'll be 100% safe with the extra `linelength=$((linelength))`. Or you could use a single line: `linelength=$(( $(head -n1 file | wc -c) ))`. Choose your style!

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
sed -i -e '1 w /dev/stdout' -e '1d' file
```

Comment: Great answer! I removed unnecessary part... I wonder if it'll work for Mikael.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this do you mind giving me a little more detail right now I get an error? `sed: -e: No such file or directory`

Comment: This one-liner prints 1st line from the `file` to `stdout` and trims that 1st line from the `file`.

Comment: Very nice! I've never seen the redirection inside a sed command before.

Comment: @Mikael what version of sed do you have?

Comment: `sed -i` creates a temporary file. Therefore this does not work if there disk space is too small.

Answer (score 3):

Show first line and delete it:

```
 head -1 file
 sed -i 1d file
```

This does, however, implicitly create a temporary file. A better solution could be [sponge](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) as pointed out in this article about **[“In-place” editing of files](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/).**

Comment: `sed -i` creates a temporary file.

Comment: `sed -i 1d test` gives me: "sed: 1: "test": undefined label 'est'"

Comment: @jofel Yes, but only if the memory is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it elegant, but here is a potential way:

```
# Find the number of characters in the first line
BYTES=$(head -n 1 file | wc -c)
# Shift all the data in-place
dd if=file of=file bs=1 skip=$BYTES conv=notrunc
# Remove the extra bytes on the end
truncate -s -$BYTES file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard utilities (except of `dd`) to modify a file inplace without any temporary file.

One solution which might work is:

```
LINELENGTH=$(head -1 test.txt | wc -c)
tail -n +2 test.txt | dd of=test.txt conv=notrunc
truncate -s -$LINELENGTH test.txt
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11074/15241 for discussion of this topic.

***EDIT:***

As the file is downloaded first with curl (see comments). There is another option:

```
curl URL | sed -e "1w first_line.txt" -e "1d" > rest.txt
firstline=$(cat first_line.txt)
rm first_line.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have enough ram:

```
contents=$(cat file) 
echo "$contents" | sed -n '1 !p' > file
```

Alternatively, use ed:

```
ed file
2,$wq
```